# Who can tell me which version is stable among Tomcat 6.0

Tags: tomcat6

Who can tell me which version is stable among Tomcat 6.0? Tomcat 6.0.26 or 6.0.32 or other version?

Comment: *Who can tell me which version is stable among Tomcat 6.0* The Tomcat mailing list.

Answer (score 2):

I typed `tomcat version` into [Google](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Search) and found [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html):

> The download pages will always show the latest stable release and any newer Alpha or Beta release if one exists.

I then clicked on `Tomcat 6.0` underneath the `Download` heading and the only version listed is `6.0.37`.